# How to create a JTree ExpansionListener

Tags: java, events, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I am having trouble creating a `TreeExpansionListener`. I thought it could be as easy as a `TreeSelectionListener`. Unfortunately I cannot find the correct interface.

Here is my listener:

```
private TreeExpansionListener createExpansionListener() {
    return (TreeExpansionEvent event) -> {
        TreePath path = event.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
        String data = node.getUserObject().toString();
        System.out.println("Expanded: " + data);
    };
}
```

The error I receive is "incompatible types: TreeExpansionListener is not a functional interface. multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in TreeExpansionListener"

compaired to my `TreeSelectionListener`:
    private TreeSelectionListener createSelectionListener() {
        return (TreeSelectionEvent e) -> {

```
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) template_tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        if ((node == null){ 
            return;
        } else {
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)   path.getLastPathComponent();
        String data = node.getUserObject().toString();
        System.out.println("Expanded: " + data);
        };
}
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a lambda expression on a non-functional interface. A functional interface has only one abstract method.

[TreeExpansionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeExpansionListener.html)

[TreeSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html)

---

```
private TreeExpansionListener createExpansionListener() {
   return new TreeExpansionListener(){
   // implement methods and do stuff...
   }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying I cannot add another lambda expression to another non-functional interface? So I would have to expand it as `private TreeExpansionListener createExpansionListener(){DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)   path.getLastPathComponent();
        String data = node.getUserObject().toString();
        System.out.println("Expanded: " + data);};`

Comment: K This indeed works. I fail to see why a lambda expression would not work, unless the functional interface is the tree and not the listener as i think.